# Preserve column order after ColumTransformer

Tags: scikit-learn, pandas, feature-engineering

I'm using `Pipeline` and `ColumnTransformer` modules from `sklearn` library to perform feature engineering on my dataset.

The dateset initially looks like this:

| date | date_block_num | shop_id | item_id | item_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02.01.2013 | 0 | 59 | 22154 | 999.00 |
| 03.01.2013 | 0 | 25 | 2552 | 899.00 |
| 05.01.2013 | 0 | 25 | 2552 | 899.00 |
| 06.01.2013 | 0 | 25 | 2554 | 1709.05 |
| 15.01.2013 | 0 | 25 | 2555 | 1099.00 |

```
$> data.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2935849 entries, 0 to 2935848
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column          Dtype  
---  ------          -----  
 0   date            object 
 1   date_block_num  object  
 2   shop_id         object  
 3   item_id         object  
 4   item_price      float64
dtypes: float64(2), int64(3), object(1)
memory usage: 134.4+ MB
```

Then I have the following transformations:

```
num_column_transformer = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ("std_scaler", StandardScaler(), make_column_selector(dtype_include=np.number)),
    ],
    remainder="passthrough"
)

num_pipeline = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ("percent_item_cnt_day_per_shop", PercentOverTotalAttributeWholeAdder(
            attribute_percent_name="shop_id",
            attribute_total_name="item_cnt_day",
            new_attribute_name="%_item_cnt_day_per_shop")
        ),
        ("percent_item_cnt_day_per_item", PercentOverTotalAttributeWholeAdder(
            attribute_percent_name="item_id",
            attribute_total_name="item_cnt_day",
            new_attribute_name="%_item_cnt_day_per_item")
        ),
        ("percent_sales_per_shop", SalesPerAttributeOverTotalSalesAdder(
            attribute_percent_name="shop_id",
            new_attribute_name="%_sales_per_shop")
        ),
        ("percent_sales_per_item", SalesPerAttributeOverTotalSalesAdder(
            attribute_percent_name="item_id",
            new_attribute_name="%_sales_per_item")
        ),
        ("num_column_transformer", num_column_transformer),
    ]
)
```

The first four `Transformers` create four new different numeric variables and the last one applies `StandardScaler` over all the numerical values of the dataset.

After executing it, I get the following data:

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -0.092652 | -0.765612 | -0.173122 | -0.756606 | -0.379775 | 02.01.2013 | 0 | 59 | 22154 |
| -0.092652 | 1.557684 | -0.175922 | 1.563224 | -0.394319 | 03.01.2013 | 0 | 25 | 2552 |
| -0.856351 | 1.557684 | -0.175922 | 1.563224 | -0.394319 | 05.01.2013 | 0 | 25 | 2552 |
| -0.092652 | 1.557684 | -0.17613 | 1.563224 | -0.396646 | 06.01.2013 | 0 | 25 | 2554 |
| -0.092652 | 1.557684 | -0.173278 | 1.563224 | -0.380647 | 15.01.2013 | 0 | 25 | 2555 |

1. **How could I preserve the column order and names?** After that, I want to do feature engineering over categorical variables and my Transformers make use of the feature column name.
2. Am I using correctly the Scikit-Learn API?

**EDIT:**

I'd expect the following output:

| date | date_block_num | shop_id | item_id | item_price | %_item_cnt_day_per_shop | %_item_cnt_day_per_item | %_sales_per_shop | %_sales_per_item |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02.01.2013 | 0 | 59 | 22154 | -0.092652 | -0.765612 | -0.173122 | -0.756606 | -0.379775 |
| 03.01.2013 | 0 | 25 | 2552 | -0.092652 | 1.557684 | -0.175922 | 1.563224 | -0.394319 |
| 05.01.2013 | 0 | 25 | 2552 | -0.856351 | 1.557684 | -0.175922 | 1.563224 | -0.394319 |
| 06.01.2013 | 0 | 25 | 2554 | -0.092652 | 1.557684 | -0.17613 | 1.563224 | -0.396646 |
| 15.01.2013 | 0 | 25 | 2555 | -0.092652 | 1.557684 | -0.173278 | 1.563224 | -0.380647 |

As you can see, columns `5`, `6`, `7`, and `8` from the output corresponds to the first four columns in the original dataset. For example, I don't know where the `item_price` feature lies in the outputted table.

Comment: I would be glad to help, but I do not get what you are trying to do, could you add and expected output table?

Comment: Please, find it at the end of the post in the edit section. Thank you @JulioJesus